# Why isn't the dimension of the space of curvature-like tensors equal to the dimension of the Grassmannian?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, grassmannian

It's a well known fact that if $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$, then the vector space consisting of all curvature-like tensors ([see this text for a precise definition and a proof](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/curvaturelike.pdf)) has dimension $\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}$. It's also well known that any curvature-like tensor $R$ is determined by its sectional curvatures (i.e, the values $R(x, y, x, y)$ with $x, y$ going through all of $V$). The sectional curvature can be thought of as a function $K: \mathrm{Gr}_2(V) \to \mathbb{R}$. In my mind these two separate facts appear to be in contradiction: if the sectional curvatures determine $R$, shouldn't the vector space consisting of all curvature-like tensors have the same dimension as $\mathrm{Gr}_2(V)$ (which has dimension $2(n-2)$)? Can someone explain what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\text{Gr}_2(V)$ is not a vector space.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Can't believe I missed that. But this still doesn't sit quite right with me...

Comment: The sectional curvature is a function on the Grassmannian. The Grassmanian is isomorphic to elements $v_1\wedge v_2$, where $v_1, v_w$ are unit tangent vectors. It extends to be a bilinear function on $\Lambda^2T_*$. Therefore, the curvature tensor is an element of $S^2\Lambda^2T^*$. So the obvious guess is that the dimension of the space of curvature tensors is $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1\right).$$ What's not obvious is that the curvature also satisfies the first Bianchi identities. If you account for that, then you get the right dimension.

Comment: Advertisement: See https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2021/01/28/RiemannCurvature.html for how to define the Riemann curvature tensor in a low tech way.

Comment: @Deane Thanks a lot!

Comment: To piggyback on Deane's comment regarding intuition for the dimension of $\mathcal{R}(V)$ (which is really just rephrasing what he said): while it is true that the map $$\mathcal{R}(V) \ni R \mapsto K^R \in C^\infty({\rm Gr}_2(V),\mathbb{R})$$is linear and injective, it is not surjective. The Bianchi identity cuts down the dimension of the range for what it has to be. In other words, it is not true that every function ${\rm Gr}_2(V) \to \mathbb{R}$ is realized as the sectional curvature function of a curvaturelike tensor on $V$.

Comment: BTW, I have since rewritten this linked write-up to be a section in a much larger text (which will see the light of the day hopefully by the end of this year or the next), and there's a nice consequence of the Ricci decomposition presented there (Theorem 17, item (ii)): the dimension of the space $\mathcal{W}(V)$ of Weyl curvaturelike tensors on $(V,g)$ is given by $$\dim \mathcal{W}(V) = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n-3)}{12}.$$How to prove it? Just compute $$\dim\mathcal{W}(V) = \dim \mathcal{R}(V) - \dim (g\wedge S(V)) = \frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$and simplify.

Comment: This in particular justifies what physicists say about the case $n=4$ regarding spacetimes: there are $20$ independent curvature components: $10$ from the Ricci tensor, and $10$ from the Weyl tensor. The usual (and unpleasant) proof they give for these dimension formulas relies heavily on combinatorics. I learned this more elegant linear algebra proof from Andrzej Derdzinski (bless the man).

Comment: @IvoTerek Your observation about the map that takes curvature tensors to their respective sectional curvature functions not being surjective is exactly where my reasoning breaks down, that's precisely what I was looking for! Thanks a lot. If you want to post these comments as an answer I'll accept it. BTW, really looking forward to that much larger text you mentioned! :) All your texts are pretty great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that while the map $$\mathcal{R}(V) \ni R \mapsto K^R\in {\rm C}^\infty({\rm Gr}_2(V), \mathbb{R})$$is linear and injective, it is not surjective. The Bianchi identity cuts down the dimension of the range for what it has to be or, in other words, it is not true that every smooth map ${\rm Gr}_2(V) \to \mathbb{R}$ arises as the sectional curvature function of some curvaturelike tensor on $V$.

To elaborate more on the proof of this dimension formula, writing $S^2(V)$ for the space of symmetric bilinear forms on $V$, one considers the Bianchi map ${\sf b} \colon S^2(V^{\wedge 2}) \to (V^*)^{\wedge 4}$ given by $${\sf b}(R)(x,y,z,w) = \frac{1}{3}(R(x,y,z,w)+R(y,z,x,w)+R(z,x,y,w)),$$and note that ${\sf b}$ is surjective with kernel $\ker {\sf b} = \mathcal{R}(V)$, so $$\dim S^2(V^{\wedge 2}) = \dim \mathcal{R}(V) + \dim ((V^*)^{\wedge 4})$$reads $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1\right) = \dim\mathcal{R}(V) + {n \choose 4}$$and directly gives $\dim \mathcal{R}(V) = n^2(n^2-1)/12$. To see why surjectivity of ${\sf b}$ holds, observe that the symmetry group $S_4$ acts on all rank $4$ tensor spaces over $V$ simply by permuting the arguments, and that ${\sf b}(\sigma\cdot R) = {\rm sgn}(\sigma) {\sf b}(R)$ holds, as well as ${\sf b}(\zeta)=\zeta$ for every $\zeta \in (V^*)^{\wedge 4}$.

Another consequence of this is the formula for the dimension of the space $\mathcal{W}(V)$ of Weyl curvature tensors in $V$, i.e., the kernel of the abstract Ricci contraction map ${\rm Ric}\colon \mathcal{R}(V) \to S^2(V)$, once one has shown that $$\mathcal{R}(V) = (g\wedge S^2(V))\oplus \mathcal{W}(V), $$where $\wedge$ stands for the Kulkarni-Nomizu product of symmetric bilinear forms. Then $$\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \dim\mathcal{W}(V)$$directly gives us that $$\dim \mathcal{W}(V) = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n-3)}{12}.$$